# What do you call a person who loves facts?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone who loves learning and knowing and saying random facts??

Comment: At one end of the spectrum we might be descrbing a savant - think Dustin Hoffman in the movie Rainman - while at the other end we might consider such a person to be a rather myopic scholar. In the UK of the 1950's and 60's, we called such people "train spotters".

Comment: Or a fact-lover.

Comment: I find this question different enough from the similar one to vote to reopen.  But it would be a better question with a sample sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Hm, maybe a "trivia buff". So for instance, if the subject were random movie facts, you could call them a "movie trivia buff".

Comment: Your answer would be strengthened with some documentation.  But I for one already upvoted, since I believe this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Philomath. From [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philomath):

> A philomath (/ˈfɪləmæθ/; Greek: φίλος philos ("beloved", "loving", as in philosophy or philanthropy) + Greek μανθάνειν manthanein, math- ("to learn", as in polymath)) is a lover of learning and studying

Answer (score -1):

Your context is pretty wide. However, what you're describing sounds to me like a new, budding, form of stereotype, *a sign of the times*, if you like.

I might just call it [**data-hungry**](https://www.wsj.com/articles/how-to-feed-a-data-hungry-public-1438039860).

I'd refrain from using the word "learning", though.

It's just information. As in not knowledge.